# Ошибка инициализации

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

покажу на скрине ошибку, NaN. Помогите пожалуйста, Я незнаю  как с ней справиться

```
 /* демо вычисления */  
$(function(){
  $("#demo7").click(function(){
  var m1 = $(".m1").attr("data");
  var Pup = $(".pup").attr("data");
  var Pzh = $(".pzh").attr("data");
  var p = (1+m1)*Pup*Pzh/(Pzh+m1*Pup);
    if (isNaN(p)) { //производим проверку при делении на нуль,
    p = 0; //чтобы результат возвращалось бы не NaN, а число 0
}
  var Ptc=p.toFixed(3); //округлим результат в Демо до десятых 
  var V = $(".v").attr("data");
  var G=(Ptc*V)/(1+m1);
  var Gtc=G.toFixed(2);
  $(".m1").val(m1);
  $(".pup").val(Pup);
  $(".pzh").val(Pzh);
  $(".p").val(Ptc); 
  $(".v").val(V);
  $("#g").val(Gtc);  
  }); 
  });
<form name="forma1" style="background-color:#44944A;"> <!-- поменяю цвет формы -->
<div id="resizable">
<br>
<!--"подрасчёт 3.3"-->
<table align="center">
<p align="center">Количество сухого тампонажного цемента</p>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Жидкостно-цементное отношение;</div><input name="t26" id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)" class="m1" data="0.5">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Плотность цемента т/м<sup>3</sup>.</div><input name="t27" id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4"  maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)" class="pup" data="3.15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Плотность жидкости затворения, т/м<sup>3</sup>.</div><input name="t28" id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4"  maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)" class="pzh" data="1.08">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Плотность тампонажного раствора;</div><input name="t29" id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)" class="p">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Общий объем тампонажного раствора;</div><input name="t30" id="t30" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)" class="v" data="2.828">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle8();">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить Демо" id="demo7">
<input type="text" name="res8" id="g" size="10">
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ладно, уж я сам исправил свой скрипт, и там лулчше всего подходил не parseInt, а parseFloat

Исправленный скрипт

```
     /* демо вычисления */  
$(function(){
  $("#demo7").click(function(){
var m1 = parseFloat($(".m1").attr("data"));
var Pup = parseFloat($(".pup").attr("data"));
var Pzh =  parseFloat($(".pzh").attr("data"));
  var p = (1+m1)*Pup*Pzh/(Pzh+m1*Pup);
  var Ptc=p.toFixed(3); //округлим результат в Демо до десятых 
  var V = $(".v").attr("data");
  var G=(Ptc*V)/(1+m1);
  var Gtc=G.toFixed(2);
  $(".m1").val(m1);
  $(".pup").val(Pup);
  $(".pzh").val(Pzh);
  $(".p").val(Ptc); 
  $(".v").val(V);
  $("#g").val(Gtc);  
  }); 
  });
```

И правильные вычисления, а при parseInt, получалось "непойми что"

[image: Исправленный вычисления]
Спасибо, что попытались помочь.

Comment: если вы хотите дополнить вопрос: используйте кнопку _править_ под вопросом

Comment: прочитайте еще [про отладку кода](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1408&rub=28), хотя бы про вывод на консоль промежуточных значений, в дальнейшем поможет искать ошибки и их устранять.

Answer (score 1):

На картинке видно, что одно из значений - `NaN`, соответственно все последующие операции с этим значением так же будут возвращать `NaN`.

Добавьте проверку, что текущее значение не `NaN` перед использованием этого значения.

Answer (score 0):

Значение NaN говорит о том, что в результате вычислений вы получили не число, а что-то непонятное. К примеру, если вы слово "холодильник" умножите на число 5, то в результате получите неизвестно что.

Тут у Вас тоже самое, вы получаете строки через функцию $("*").attr("data") и пытаетесь их умножить и сложить друг с другом. К слову сложение у Вас в этом случае тоже неправильно, т.к. "1" + "0.5" = "10.5". И я думаю это не то, что Вы ожидаете.

Используйте конвертацию в число перед математическими операциями.

```
var m1 = parseInt($(".m1").attr("data"),10);
var Pup =  parseInt($(".pup").attr("data"),10);
var Pzh =  parseInt($(".pzh").attr("data"),10);
var V = parseInt($(".v").attr("data"),10);
```